# How can I display a background image in a system-sent email in Outlook?

Tags: c#, html, css, outlook, html-email

How can I display a background image in a system-sent email in Outlook?

- The text in the email needs to be on top of the image.
- The text will be arranged using a table
- I do not need to support any email client other than Outlook on desktops.
- I figured out how to include images, but not as a background. The image needs to be a background for the text.

Here's what I've tried, based on articles that told me to use background as an attribute rather than the css property background-image. (Yes, I tried CSS as well, but it doesn't work in Outlook).

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <table height="1685" width="1200"  background="https://images.pexels.com/photos/459793/pexels-photo-459793.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=800&w=1200">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' fill='true' stroke='false' style='width:600px;height:800px;'>
        <v:fill type='tile' src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/459793/pexels-photo-459793.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=800&w=1200' color='#baeef7' />
        <v:textbox inset='0,0,0,0'>
        <![endif]-->
        <tr>
           <td>
                Test</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://backgrounds.cm/ and https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email . Stig's technique is the best of breed solution for Outlook as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The `background` element is not supported in Outlook (only when there is a URL). You may try to refer to the embedded attachment instead (can be hidden).

Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200%28v%3Doffice.12%29)